# Python hangs on `import paramiko`

Tags: python, python-import, paramiko

I've been debugging a script that imports the Paramiko library from Python at the beginning. Specifically, it calls `import paramiko` on the first line.

Every once in awhile, this hangs indefinitely. (It should import almost instantaneously...) When this happens, I quit the script, run `pip install paramiko --upgrade`, and rerun. This fixes my error for awhile until I need to reinstall again.

My system:

- Ubuntu 18.04.2
- Python 2.7.15rc1
- paramiko 2.4.2

Comment: You should include the version of Python and of paramiko that you're using

Comment: How the library has installed in the beginning? Maybe use requirements file with specific version of lib?

Comment: I installed the library originally by typing `pip install paramiko`.

Comment: I also have the same issue, and as this "hangs on" does not happen often for a scheduled crontab job, it is really difficult to debug and find out what is going wrong.  This happens often on Windows task scheduler  (e.g. 1 /100 chances), with python  3.10.4 and paramiko 3.0.0